# Symfony2 entities and createFormBuilder

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine, repository

I need help with Symfony2 (2.8)

Created two entities Category and CategoryLang. It will be a categories.

```
<?php

namespace CreLabs\Bundle\SettingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CreLabs\Bundle\SettingBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{

    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true, options={"default": 1})
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CategoryLang", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $locales;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $updated_at;
```

CategoryLang. It will be a translation of my categories.

```
<?php

namespace CreLabs\Bundle\SettingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="category_lang")
 */
class CategoryLang
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="locales", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2)
     */
    protected $locale;
```

Now i trying add createFormBuilder Category Entity + CategoryLang Entities fields, but can not see normally form. Only can use array('mapped' => false and forward data from fields.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($category);
        $form = $form
            ->add('locale', HiddenType::class, array('mapped' => false, 'data' => $locale))
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('mapped' => false, 'data' => $name))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('mapped' => false, 'required' => false, 'data' => $description))
            ->add($label, SubmitType::class, array('label' => $label));
        $form = $form->getForm();
```

By the way have CategoryRepository with custom query

```
public function getCategory($category_id, $locale)
    {
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('SettingBundle:Category');
        $fields = array('p.id', 'category_info.name', 'category_info.description', 'p.status, category_info.locale');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select($fields)
            ->innerJoin('SettingBundle:CategoryLang', 'category_info', 'WITH', 'category_info.category = p.id')
            ->where('p.id = :category_id AND category_info.locale = :locale')
            ->setParameter('category_id', $category_id)
            ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
            ->getQuery();

        $result = $query->getOneOrNullResult() != NULL ? new ArrayCollection($query->getSingleResult()) : false;

        return $result;
    }
```

Problems:
1. getCategory() -> return not object, but array or ArrayCollection. Can not be reused then need update fields in database.

```
/* @var $category Category */
        $category = $this->getCategory($category_id, $form['locale']);

        if ($category) {
//            $category->setUpdatedAt(new ArrayCollection());
            $locale = new CategoryLang();
            $locale->setName($form['name']);
            $locale->setDescription($form['description']);
            $category->addLocale($locale);
            $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
            $entityManager->persist($category);
            $entityManager->flush($category);
        }
```

2. Can not get in create form builder information from child table.

Where is my problem? Can anybody help me understand my mistakes?

Comment: Why you don't use doctrine behavior bundle to translate entity? You can check the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583444/symfony-translations-on-dynamic-content/38912918#38912918

Comment: It is only one solution to use Behavior Bundle?

Comment: When I try remove $category->removeLocale($category->getLocales()[0]);
and do persist and flush not see any changes. Looks like removeLocale does not work

Comment: An easy way to remove private owned entities is using doctrine orphan removal: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal